# Subtract certain text

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have the following sample from a column:

```
ABC1 Walsall - ABC: Ground Floor, One Tower, 123 Bridge Street, London AB1 1JZ
ADF6 Wembley
KLM1 Bedford - ABC: 6 Another Street, Birmingham CD40 1HP
```

Some cells are blank or have a different format, but all start with a 4 characters code and then a city.

I would like to subtract that code and place it into a new array and city name into a different array.

I have tried the following script, but it doesn't work.

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("ID");
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Subtract");
  var range = sheet.getDataRange();
  var data = range.getValues();
  var locCode = [];
  for (i=1; i<data.length; i++) {
    locCode.push(data[i][0]);
  }
  locCode.slice(5, locCode.length);
  Logger.log(locCode);

}
```

Could you help me with that please?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assuming you have always 4 characters for the code, followed by the city name, optionally followed by space, dash, and other characters

```
var cities = [];
for (i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
  var cellText = data[i][0];
  // extract the 4 first characters
  locCode.push(cellText.substring(0, 4));
  // add " -" at the end of text to make sure even 'ADF6 Wembley' has the 
  // 'CODE CITY - ...' format,
  // then extract any thing after the code and before the first "-", ignoring the space
  cities.push(cellText.substring(5, (cellText + " -").indexOf("-") - 1))
}
```

Comment: TypeError: Function substring cannot be found in Object 1 ... this is the error I get (and got it when I've tried this method) ....

Comment: i run the same code, except i use `var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();` and iterate from `i = 0`.
`Logger.log(locCode);
  Logger.log(cities); ` gives me:
[17-09-05 17:31:23:459 CEST] [ABC1, ADF6, KLM1]
[17-09-05 17:31:23:459 CEST] [Walsall, Wembley, Bedford]

Comment: I replace `getSheetByName()` with `getActiveSheet()` and I manage to get the code, but for the cities I get only blanks for each row. Also, I will need to use `getSheetByName()` as I have multiple sheets on that Spreadsheet.

Comment: Also, when I use it with the original file, I keep get this error `TypeError: Cannot find function substring in object 1. (line 11, file "Code")Dismiss`.

Comment: I have updated your code and added `if(typeof cellText === 'number') {continue;};`. The code is working perfect now. Thanks for your help !!!